# Product definition does not export the VM parameters correctly when launching an Eclipse Application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I defined these VM parameters on the Launching tab of the product definition:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED
```

When I launch the app (from the Overview tab) the launch fails.

```
Fehler: Hauptklasse java.base.java.text=ALL-UNNAMED konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
Ursache: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.base.java.text=ALL-UNNAMED
```

The Run Configuration contains the following VM Arguments:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED
```

The `--add-opens` appears just once. I have tried defining the options all on one line but the result is the same.

Adding `--add-opens` to the last two items fixes the problem and the app starts.

Is this a bug or should I be declaring these options in a different way?

(Using Eclipse 4.28, fully updated)

Comment: IMHO that should be a [pull request here](https://github.com/eclipse-pde/eclipse.pde) rather than a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the issue I opened on Github: https://github.com/eclipse-pde/eclipse.pde/issues/735.

It seems that it's valid to define the arguments like this:

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED
```

The launcher now starts the app correctly.